# Android custom popup

Tags: java, android, dialog

So I have a layout I created and I want to use that as a *popup* on a different layout.

I was able to figure out how to call it but it doesn't look right.
It called the ENTIRE layout, not just the content of it.

This is what I did:

```
this.textAbsType.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    View absenceTypePopup = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AbsenceTypePopup, null);

    Dialog absenceTypeDialog = new Dialog(context);
    absenceTypeDialog.SetContentView(absenceTypePopup);
    absenceTypeDialog.Show();

    this.btnAbsTypePopupClose = absenceTypeDialog.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnAbsTypePopupClose);

    this.btnAbsTypePopupClose.Click += (object sender2, EventArgs e2) => {
        absenceTypeDialog.Dismiss();
    };
};
```

So when textAbsType (TextView) is called, popup is shown. 
And 2nd event if for the button on the popup to cancel it.

But this is how the popup shows up:

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

The extra black border on the top is part of the axml design file.

**Question:** 
How can I get rid of that so I can just view the *TableLayout* as the *popup*?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the line `absenceTypeDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in your code and it will go away.

**Updated code**:

```
this.textAbsType.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

    Dialog absenceTypeDialog = new Dialog(context);
    absenceTypeDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    absenceTypeDialog.setContentView(R.layout.AbsenceTypePopup);
    absenceTypeDialog.Show();

    this.btnAbsTypePopupClose = absenceTypeDialog.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnAbsTypePopupClose);

    this.btnAbsTypePopupClose.Click += (object sender2, EventArgs e2) => {
        absenceTypeDialog.Dismiss();
    };
};
```

Comment: This is how I was able to do it:  absenceTypeDialog.RequestWindowFeature(1);

Comment: Yes, it will work as well. 1 is for FEATURE_NO_TITLE.